# Find Average using Array of Objects/Object Array

Tags: java, arrays, object

this is such a simple problem but for some reason, I cant wrap my head around Array of Objects or Object Arrays. All I have to do is take in 5 user inputs, and create a class called Height, create object array and store user inputs into obj array and print the average. I'm kinda stuck.

```
class Height{
    int total=0;
    int count=0;
    public Height(int y) {
        total=total+y;
        count++;
    }
    public void print() {
        System.out.print("The average is: "+total/count);
    }
}

public class ObjectArray {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 5 heights in inches: ");
        int[] x=new int[5];
        int total=0;
        for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
            x[i]=s.nextInt();
        }
        Height[] h=new Height[x.length];
        for(int y=0;y<x.length;y++) {
            h[y]=new Height(x[y]);
        }
        h.print();
    }
}
```

Maybe I'm over complicating it. The problem right now is that I cannot invoke h.print();. I've tried different iterations, ex: taking out the print method and doing all the printing after every iteration.

Comment: Are you supposed to create an array of `Height` or have an array stored inside `Height`? And `h.print()` fails because `h` is an array, not a single object

Comment: You are creating new object evry time in for loop which is the problem! You wanted this on same object, but you are creating new object everytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is wrong. Your `Height` class appears to be responsible for the evaluation of the mean value. Hence, you should put all values inside a single `Height` instance, instead of generating a new instance for each user value.

However, `h` is an array of `Height`s object, while `print()` method is defined on a single `Height` instance. In order to call such method, you have to access one of the objects contained in `h`, that is `h[0].print()`.

Comment: ok thanks, the h is an array part makes sense, but if I use single instance of Height and put all values into a single instance, then theres no point in using Object arrays right? Back to the drawing board, let me think about this a little more.

Comment: You are right, there is no point in using array. If you're willing to use it, you need to change `Height` in order to keep just a single value, and use them later to evaluate the mean.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your goal is simply to print the average of all the heights recieved via user input.

Your code in your main method is a tad confusing, so correct me if I'm wrong in any of the examples I give here. You should, instead of creating the `x[]` array, simply add the user input for the five values to `Height.total` in a *for loop,* and increase the `Height.count` variable by one each loop through. This should look something like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    // System.out.println("Please enter the next height: ");
    Height.total += s.nextDouble();
    Height.count++;
}
```

Then, you can run `Height.print();`.

I would also recommend adding a `System.out.print("");` command to let the user know that they should enter the next value. That's the comment I left in the example code I gave above.

Comment: Yea, but the whole topic/main idea is to use Object Arrays, I mean if 
 I didn't have to, it would be a piece of cake. My approach in main was to handle all the user inputs, create the object array, and set the user input values into the Object Array by passing a int variable and invoking the constructor each time and call a print method. I see the flaw in that logic now that in the for loop, a new object gets created every time.

Comment: @Java_Beginner Did you get your problem solved, or do you still need some help? If you do I'll edit my answer and take into account what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yea thanks, more or less. I think I know what I need to do and what to avoid. Still a work in progress but if you wouldn't mind posting how you would approach it as well. Never hurts to see others approach as it may be a lot more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You have to design your `Height` in a way that match your requirement :

- you need different `Height` with for each one a value
- you need to know how many instances there is

For that, you need a private value, and a static counter :

```
class Height {

    private int value = 0;

    private static int count = 0;    // static => nb of instances

    public Height(int y) {
        value = y;
        count++;
    }

    public static int averageOf(Height... heights) {
        return Arrays.stream(heights).mapToInt(h -> h.value).sum() / count;
    }
}
```

To get the average, because it doesn't depend on a particular instance, you can have a static method, that sums all the value of the `Height` given and divide by the nb of instance

And use like :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int nb = 5;
    System.out.println("Enter " + nb + " heights in inches: ");

    Height[] heights = new Height[nb];
    for (int i = 0; i < heights.length; i++) {
        heights[i] = new Height(Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine()));
    }

    System.out.println("Average is " + Height.averageOf(heights));
}
```

Comment: ok just read more in depth on static instances and variables and that makes a lot of sense. But I still see that we are creating a new heights object of type Height in the main for loop. Is that considered best practice or efficient is you had a problem similar to this where you need to take vars and set into object arrays?

Comment: @Java_Beginner depends your requirement, only for getting an average you don't need an other class, after for you maybe you need it